# Pastries probability problem (hard for me, easy for others)

Tags: probability, statistics

Some friends are in a bar. On the table there are two platters. In one of them there are 12 muffins and 13 donuts . On the other, there are 12 donuts and 4 muffins. If by chance someone choose one of these platters and also by chance take one of the pastries:

**a) what's the probability of picking up a donut?**

**b) what's the probability of picking up a muffin?**

I don't know how to solve. 
And I can't understand why the answer isn't the number of donuts/total or # of muffins/total

Comment: Is it a 50/50 choice on which platter they choose?

Comment: To your last point;  suppose one platter held a million donuts and the other held one muffin. Then the probability of getting a muffin is $\frac 12$ because there is a $\frac 12$ chance of picking the muffin platter.  The overwhelming number of donuts on the other platter is irrelevant.

Comment: It doesn't say so, but I'm assuming it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every pastry is equally likely. Each pastry in the second tray is taken with probability $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{12+4}$

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a good way to get a grasp on a problem is to reframe the problem with extreme numbers. In this case, you could imagine one platter with 1000 donuts and 1 muffin and the other platter has 1 of each.  Even though there are 1001 donuts and 2 muffins, you can see that choosing a muffin is not out of the question. A 50% chance of choosing the second platter and then a 50% chance of getting a muffin.

To answer your specific problem, one simple way is to make a probability tree. The first branch is 50% chance of getting each platter and the next branching is your chance of picking each item on the platter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple picture to help to grasp the idea as turkeyhundt suggested in his post. I hope you can see that the probability of selecting a muffin is then

$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{4+12} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{12}{12+13} 
= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{6}{25} = \frac{73}{200} = 0.365
$$

And the probability of selecting a donut is then

$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{12}{4+12} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{13}{12+13} 
= \frac{3}{8} + \frac{13}{50} = \frac{127}{200} = 0.635
$$

Note that the probabilities sum to $1$, which is a good sanity check! I hope this helps with the intuition, I also assume that the probability of choosing one plate from the other is equal (a half).

[image: Probability tree]

Comment: best answer ever. thanks!!